# Cómo generar código autoincrementable con nombre y letra

Tags: mysql

Lo que quiero es que al ingresar un producto en mi base de datos MYSQL, éste genere un código propio de identificación de esta forma:

- P001 - Detergente
- P002 - Aceite
- P003 - Arroz

Me sugirieron que lo haga con procedimiento almacenado, pero no sé cómo.
¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Siempre sera el prefijo: P00 ? porque el 1,2,3,4 lo puedes tener con un autoincrement...

Comment: Planeas que ese campo generado sea tu llave primaria?

Comment: Esto lo puedes resolver más fácilmente con PHP o con el lenguaje que sea que estés utilizando (es solo una recomendación)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blB5HMKJ5ks Aqui encontré la solución sin usar auto increment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como te dijo Leandro el codigo identificador de una tabla es recomendable ser un dato numérico, lo que podrías hacer es un campo extra que funcione como un segundo código, llamado tal vez código_secundario. 
Puedes hacerlo con Procedimiento Almacenado, te doy un pequeño ejemplo:

```
DELIMITER$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_Generar_Codigo$$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Generar_Codigo(
OUT p_codigo_secundario VARCHAR(4) 
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE contador INT;
    BEGIN
        SET contador= (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM Producto); 
        IF(contador<10)THEN
            SET p_codigo_secundario= CONCAT('P00',contador);
            ELSE IF(contador<100) THEN
                SET p_codigo_secundario= CONCAT('P0',contador);
                ELSE IF(contador<1000)THEN
                    SET p_codigo_secundario= CONCAT('P',contador);
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF; 
    END;
END$$
```

Con eso puedes generar codigos como necesitas con la estructura 'P001'

Comment: sería más escalable si utilizases la funcion [`LPAD`][http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lpad-function.php] de mysql, así el codigo queda más claro y es escalable

Comment: La función LPAD te agrega caracteres a la izquierda? De qué manera se podría implementar? Podrías mostrar un ejemplo?

Comment: 1º el link se pegó mal, le agregó un ] al final y no puedo editar. este es el link real http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lpad-function.php
2º la función está de esta forma: `LPAD(string_original, largo_deseado, relleno), ej: LPAD('11', 5, '0') = '00011'`. El único detalle sería que se necesitaría saber de antemano la cantidad estimada de de productos a existir, para así definir el largo_deseado, pero con un largo de 8, se tiene bastante margen

Answer (score 4):

La solución propuesta por Christopher, en base a la de Leando, es bastante buena. A pesar de ello, más que un `store procedure`, lo haría con triggers, de forma tal que previo a la inserción de un nuevo producto en tu tabla, se calcule este segundo campo. Por ejemplo, este sería un trigger que solucionaría esto:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON tabla_productos FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE next_id INT;

  SET next_id = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='tabla_productos');
  SET NEW.codigo_secundario = CONCAT('P', LPAD(next_id, 8, '0'));
END
```

Explicando por partes el código:

1. Se declara una variable para recuperar desde el esquema el próximo id a utilizar (al ser autoincremental y el trigger correr previo a la inserción, **no tenemos** el valor para el id
2. Se setea el campo `codigo_secundario` como el próximo id a insertar con un padding (relleno) de ceros por delante, hasta completar un string de largo 8 junto con un prefijo con la letra `P` . El largo de 8, lo tomé ya que te permite tener `10^8-1` productos en total. Si estimas que tendrás más de 99.999.999 de productos, incrementa este valor o decrementalo, si tendrás mucho menos que eso.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos

Answer (score 3):

No se diseña de esa forma un identificador para la tabla, el id debe ser algo simple un numerico secuencial o guid.

Un campo calculado no es recomendado ya que no cumple con las formas normales

[Normalización de bases de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos)

en tu caso define un campo numerico secuencial que lleve los valores 1,2,3 etc y luego otro campo que represente la letra P, no sabria decirte que nombre ponerle a este campo porque seria algo relacionado con el negocio

Cuando le muestres los datos al usuario podrias componer el valor uniendo el campo de letra con el secuancial numerico

Comment: Ninguna forma normal exige que una clave primaria (o foránea) sea numérica (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos#Primera_Forma_Normal_.281FN.29).

Pero el espacio que ocupa un campo no numérico y su correspondiente índice sí será mas costoso.

Comment: Pero yo no solo mencione que sea numerico, podria ser un Guid. El tema es no definir un campo compuesto por dos datos diferentes

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar, si es php, [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php)

y asi agregar ceros adelante del codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Me topé con el mismo problema, estuve investigando un poco y me recomiendan no utlizar `information_schema` en vez de eso es mas recomendable utilizar [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) y `Limit 1`

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON tabla_productos FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE next_id INT;

    SET next_id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM tabla_productos Limit 1;
    SET NEW.codigo_secundario = CONCAT('P', LPAD(next_id + 1, 8, '0'));
  END
```