# Explicación de una Consulta MySQL dentro de Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Buscando la solución a un problema para generar un Identificador AutoIncrementable con texto, encontré la solución [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15932/c%C3%B3mo-generar-c%C3%B3digo-autoincrementable-con-nombre-y-letra) en una pregunta de StackOverflow.

El Problema ahora (aunque me soluciona mi Problema) es que no entiendo el Código SQL:

```
SET next_id =   (
                    SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
                    FROM information_schema.TABLES 
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() 
                          AND TABLE_NAME='tabla_productos'
                );
```

Entiendo que hace una consulta para almacenar el ID, pero no comprendo los parametros de la consulta y me interesa saber que es lo que esta haciendo.

Comment: Pues lo que hace tu consulta en palabras entendibles, es despertar a un monstruo que se llama [`information_schema`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html) para una operación banal como es obtener el último valor auto incremental de una determinada tabla. Me pregunto: ¿hay que despertar al monstruo para esa nimiedad cuando se puede hacer con [`LAST_INSERT_ID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)  o simplemente ordenando la tabla y aplicando un `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Aquí hay un enlace que tambien podría servirte. [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332790/c%c3%b3mo-incrementar-%c3%baltimos-d%c3%adgitos-en-una-consulta)

Comment: @A.Cedano la alternativa a a esa consulta como pudiera quedar utilizando el `LAST_INSERT_ID` y `Limit 1`

Comment: @A.Cedano utilicé el siguiente código: `SET @_idEmployee = (SELECT last_insert_id() FROM employees LIMIT 1);
    SET NEW.idSecondary = CONCAT("SB",LPAD(@_idEmployee+1,7,"0"));`

Comment: Ok, incluso, si estás en un `TRIGGER` de tipo `AFTER INSERT` puedes obtener el último `ID` con algo como `NEW.idSecondary`

Comment: @A.Cedano al final use `SET @_idEmployee = (SELECT max(id_Employees) FROM employees);` Tuve Problemas con el `last_insert_id` desde mi aplicación.

Comment: Creo que es mejor opción. En el sitio en inglés hay discusiones sobre si `last_insert_id` es a prueba de conexiones concurrentes o no, creo que usar `max` te dará el mayor `id` en el momento, independientemente del contexto en el que estés. Tampoco he verificado eso, pues no he hecho ninguna prueba al respecto en distintos entornos, como por ejemplo varias conexiones al mismo tiempo.